# Play Json: Transforming a Reads[T] to Reads[Seq[T]] without implicits

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.1

I hava a `Reads[T]`. I would like to parse a Json object which is expected to be an array of `T`'s. Is there a simple way to obtain a `Reads[Seq[T]]` *without* defining my `Reads[T]` as implicit? Essentially, I am looking for a function that takes `Reads[T]` and returns `Reads[Seq[T]]`.

I came across `Reads.TraversableReads`, and thought that I can pass the implicit reader it needs explicitly, but this function also wants a `CanBuildForm[...]`, which does not sound like fun.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a method for this in the `Reads` companion object: `Reads.seq`.  Its parameter is usually implicit, but you can always call it explicitly if you want:

```
val a: Reads[T] = ...
val b: Reads[Seq[T]] = Reads.seq(a)
```