# How to write a Reads[Seq[T]] for a given Reads[T]?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm using the json library of the play framework version 2.2.3. I have the following json object:

```
{
    "myData":
    [
        {
            "A": "some text",
            "B": [10, 20, 30]
        },
        {
            "A": "some other text",
            "B": [15, 25, 35]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I want to deserialize this json object to a `Vector[Map[String, Vector[Int]]]`. So the result should be:

```
Vector(Map("some text" -> Vector(10, 20, 30)), Map("some other text" -> Vector(15, 25, 35)))
```

While I was trying to achieve that, I was able to write a `Reads[Map[String, Vector[Int]]]` that does it for a single entry.

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

implicit val singleEntryReads: Reads[Map[String, Vector[Int]]] = {
  (__).read(
    (__ \ "A").read[String] and
    (__ \ "B").read[Vector[Int]] tupled) map { keyAndValue =>
      val (a, b) = keyAndValue
      Map(a -> b)
    }
}
```

So the conversion works for a single entry:

```
scala> (myJsonObject \ "myData")(0).validate[Map[String, Vector[Int]]]     
res: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Map[String, Vector[Int]]] = JsSuccess(Map(some text -> Vector(10, 20, 30)))
```

But how can I write a `Reads[Vector[Map[String, Vector[Int]]]]`? My best idea was to do it similar to the answer given to [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17597659/1125413):

```
implicit val allEntriesReads: Reads[Seq[Map[String, Vector[Int]]]] = Reads.seq(singleEntryReads)
```

I tried to use it like this:

```
scala> (myJsonObject \ "myData").validate[Seq[Map[String, Vector[Int]]]]"
res2: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Seq[Map[String, Vector[Int]]]] = JsError(List(((147)/B,List(ValidationError(error.path.missing,WrappedArray()))), ((148)/B,List(ValidationError(error.path.missing,WrappedArray())))))
```

But that does not work and gives me a `JsError()`. How do I have to implement the second `Reads` to get it working that way?

Comment: What version of Play is this?

Comment: @LimbSoup It is version 2.2.3. I've updated my question with this information.

Comment: I can't even get `allEntiresReads` to compile without changing the first `Vector` to `Seq`.

Comment: @LimbSoup You are right, I got the `JsError` when using a `Seq`, not a `Vector`. But it is the `Vector` that I want to have in the end.

Comment: What is the full error?

Comment: @LimbSoup I've updated my question with the precise error message.

Comment: Using the JSON sample above (after fixing a typo), it worked for me. Your error is related to the "B" path. Is it an empty array?

Comment: @LimbSoup My json file seems to be completely valid. Does it work for you with `allEntriesReads` defined or without it? Because @wingedsubmariner says that it's not necessary to declare it. It's still not working for me, though. Weird.

Comment: @LimbSoup After careful investigation of my very large json file, I actually found a bug in it. So you are right, it works now. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to. Play! comes with an implicit (defined in the `Reads` companion object) that already does what you want:

```
implicit def traversableReads[F[_], A](implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[F[_], A, F[A]], ra: Reads[A]): Reads[F[A]]
```

If you have an implicit `Reads[A]` and an appropriate `CanBuildFrom` for the sequence type (these already exist for the standard libraries collection types, e.g. `Vector`) then this implicit will act as an implicit `Reads[F[A]]` where `F` is the collection type.

Scala lets you define an `implicit def` that itself takes implicit parameters, and it will act as an implicit value of its return type. When using your `implicit def`, Scala will search for the implicit parameters at the call site. So:

```
.validate[Seq[Map[String, Vector[Int]]]]
```

becomes:

```
.validate[Seq[Map[String, Vector[Int]]]](traversableReads)
```

which then becomes:

```
.validate[Seq[Map[String, Vector[Int]]]](traversableReads(singleEntryReads, Seq.canBuildFrom)
```

Comment: Can you please explain this in a bit more detail? If an implicit exists for this kind of task, then why does my code fail?

Comment: It looks like you are getting a `error.path.missing` error, which suggests that they key `"myData"` isn't present. It is finding the necessary `Reads` though, otherwise you would get an error about a missing implicit. You can also do `implicitly[Reads[Seq[Map[String, Vector[Int]]]]]` in the REPL and see that it finds a value. I've edited the answer to include a longer explanation.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't quite get it. Do I have to write my own implementation of `traversableReads` now? Because your last code line does not work as is. If so, how do I do it? It's hard for me to understand because the method signatures are complicated and the documentation of the library is very sparse. I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Those lines are examples of the transformations that the compiler is doing - I wasn't suggesting that you write lines like that (though they should work as is). You real error at the point is the `error.path.missing` error, you don't need to do anything more to get your `Reads` instance.

Comment: So what is wrong with my path then? What do I have to change? My problem is not solved yet.

Comment: By the way, the `implicitly` call works and finds the value, but when I try to apply the `Reads` on the data, it fails. Something must be wrong in the `singleEntryReads` but I don't know what. My json file seems to be completely valid.

Comment: Oh dear, it was a bug in my json data. You are perfectly right, everything works as expected now. It seems I'm getting blind despite my young age. Sorry for the confusion and thanks again for your correct answer.